# Connecting to Azure Databricks with user assigned managed identity

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity

**TL;DR**: Authentication to Databricks using managed identity fails due to wrong audience claim in the token.

Technical details: When acquiring token to access databricks using managed identity (with http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token API), the returned token audience is 'spn:2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d' instead of '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d'.

When trying to use the acquired token, I get the following error:
`Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d, but was: spn:2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d.`

It seems that the audience is always prefixed with 'spn:' in case of the resource being a guid and not a url.

I also tried to use the databricks app url ('https://azuredatabricks.net/') as the resource, but the token was not accepted here also.

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds (other than using the service principal method)?

Thanks!

Comment: Which service did you use the user-assigned MSI in? VM?

Comment: in Azure Container Instance

Comment: Did you decode your token in https://jwt.io/ to see its actual audience(i.e. `aud`)? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. The aud claim is "spn:2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d" instead of "2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d" (without the 'spn:') which causes the mismatch.

Comment: Could you show the details you used to get the token? Include the parameters.

Comment: The command is:
```curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d' -H Metadata:true -s```

Comment: I can also reproduce your issue with `resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`, if I use `resource=https://azuredatabricks.net/`, the token I got is `"aud": "https://azuredatabricks.net/"`, it looks good. But you said `I also tried to use the databricks app url ('https://azuredatabricks.net/') as the resource, but the token was not accepted here also.` What's the error when you use this token?

Comment: A very similar error: ```Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d, but was: https://azuredatabricks.net/.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue, it looks like a bug, [using managed identity with Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity) is still a *preview* feature.

[image]

I also test the same user-assigned managed identity with a Linux VM with the same curl command, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The observation that the issue reproduces only in ACI is important. I will open a bug in Azure.